# Rapid SCADA. Изменение интервала времени

Tags: javascript

Есть код скрипта:

```
// Расчитать шаг и скорректировать начальное и конечное значение сетки оси абсцисс
function CalcGridX() {
    var range1 = 1 / 2;  // 12 часов
    var range2 = 1 / 4;  // 6 часов
    var range3 = 1 / 12; // 2 часа
    var range = MaxX - MinX;
    var minStep;

    if (range > range1)
        minStep = 60;
    else if (range > range2)
        minStep = 30;
    else if (range > range3)
        minStep = 15;
    else
        minStep = 5;

    GridStepX = 1 / 1440 * minStep;
    MinX = Math.floor(MinX / GridStepX) * GridStepX;
    MaxX = Math.ceil(MaxX / GridStepX) * GridStepX;
}
```

который, как я думаю, выводит в графике по оси Х почасовые значения суток от 00:00 до 00:00.
Мне нужно, чтобы он выводил по 12 часов с 20:00 до 8:00 или с 8:00 до 20:00.
В javascript разбираюсь слабо и пока вообще в программировании. Прошу помощи.

P.S. еще в скрипте есть такой кусок:

```
// Расчитать диапазон значений графиков
function CalcRange() {
    MinY = Number.NaN;
    MaxY = Number.NaN;
    var minX = MinX - DiagBreak;
    var maxX = MaxX + DiagBreak; 

    for (var diagInd = 0; diagInd < DiagCnt; diagInd++) {
        var diagData = DiagDataArr[diagInd];

        for (var ptInd = 0; ptInd < PtCnt; ptInd++) {
            var x = DiagTime[ptInd];

            if (minX <= x && x <= maxX) {
                var y = diagData[ptInd][0];
                if (isNaN(MinY) || MinY > y)
                    MinY = y;
                if (isNaN(MaxY) || MaxY < y)
                    MaxY = y;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isNaN(MinY)) {
        MinY = -1;
        MaxY = 1;
    } else {
        // расчёт дополнительных полей
        var extra = MinY == MaxY ? 1 : (MaxY - MinY) * 0.05;

        // включение в диапазон нуля при отображении графика без увеличения
        var realMinY = MinY;
        var realMaxY = MaxY;

        if (MinX == 0 && MaxX == 1) {
            if (MinY > 0 && MaxY > 0)
                MinY = 0;
            else if (MinY < 0 && MaxY < 0)
                MaxY = 0;

            var newExtra = (MaxY - MinY) * 0.05;
            if (extra < newExtra)
                extra = newExtra;
        }

        // добавление дополнительных полей
        if (realMinY - MinY < extra)
            MinY -= extra;
        if (MaxY - realMaxY < extra)
            MaxY += extra;
    }
}
```

Может быть как раз в нем вся соль.